# Correlation bounds for uniformly distributed matrix?

Tags: distributions, correlation, matrix, bounds

For a uniformly or Guassian distributed $M\times N $ matrix. Is there any analytical expression in terms of $M$ and $N$ to estimate the maximum and minimum bounds of correlation between the columns of the matrix ?